# Python cx-freeze ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have a program that consists of a main script as .py and some custom modules as .pyd. All the files sit in the same directory. The main script imports the modules using `import module` syntax, and from my IDE it all works fine. But when I cx-freeze the program I get the error `dynamic module does not define init function`.

[image]

What's doubly strange is that the `quavers` module is the second import, so the first one works but then this one breaks. And there isn't much difference between the two in terms of content (just a couple of functions in each). I've also created freezed programs before with custom pyd modules and never came across this before.

What is the `init` function and why does cx-freeze need it? What does it do? Do I need to create an init function in each module that I import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I have two versions of the same module, `quavers1` and `quavers2`. I first compiled them to pyd using nuitka and then renamed the created pyd file from `quavers1` to `quavers` when cx-freezing them. The renaming post nuitka compilation was what was causing the problem. If I rename, compile in nuitka, then freeze, it works fine.